# PHP - Help with regex?

Tags: php, regex, math, eval

I wouldn't call myself a master regarding regex, i pretty much just know the basics. I've been playing around with it, but i can't seem to get the desired result. So if someone would help me, i would really appreciate it!

I'm trying to check wether unwanted words exist in a string. I'm working on a math project, and i'm gonna be using eval() to calculate the string, so i need to make sure it's safe.

The string may contain (just for example now, i'll add more functions later) the following words: (read the comments)

```
floor() // spaces or numbers are allowed between the () chars. If possible, i'd also like to allow other math functions inside, so it'd look like: floor( floor(8)*1 ).
It may contain any digit, any math sign (+ - * /) and dots/commas (,.) anywhere in the string
```

Just to be clear, here's another example: If a string like this is passed, i *do not* want it to pass:

```
9*9 + include('somefile') / floor(2) // Just a random example on something that's not allowed
```

Now that i think about it, it looks kind of complicated. I hope you can at least give me some hints.

Thanks in advance,
-Anthony

Edit: This is a bit off-topic, but if you know a better way of calculating math functions, please suggest it. I've been looking for a safe math class/function that calculates an input string, but i haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 1):

Please do not use eval() for this.

My standard answer to this question whenever it crops up:

Don't use eval (especially if the formula contains user input) or reinvent the wheel by writing your own formula parser.

Take a look at the [evalMath](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html) class on PHPClasses. It should do everything that you want in a nice safe sandbox.

Comment: I'll take a look at that class, thanks! But why shouldn't i use eval in this case? If i filter it for bad characters/words, and deny access if it doesn't pass - how could they break through?

Comment: The problem with eval in this case is that you can't filter for every possibility.

Comment: Well, almost? I mean, if anything else than the allowed characters/words are entered, the eval won't be triggered. I don't see how anything "bad" could be entered, and if the user only enters valid characters/words, nothing should go wrong? I'm just curious, it's interesting and good to know. I downloaded evalMath and it works wonderfully, thanks for the tip. Even if the eval function would work, this feels more secure - after all, that's what i was looking for in first place.

Comment: But the eval could be triggered for formulae that a regexp would consider valid, but that would (for example) trigger an error... "9 / 0". It's never good for code to trigger errors (at the very least, it looks unprofessional); but a fatal error in eval() can't be trapped except within a shutdown function.

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase your problem, you want to allow only a specific set of characters, plus certain predefined words.  The alternation operator (pipe symbol) is your friend in this case:

```
([0-9\+\-\*\/\.\,\(\) ]|floor|ceiling|other|functions)*
```

Of course, using eval is inherently dangerous, and it is difficult to guarantee that this regex will offer full protection in a language with syntax as expansive as PHP.

Comment: Would you consider a regex like this safe? Or should i try another method? Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: No, I'd only use eval like this for personal use, and then I wouldn't need the regex.  I'd look into evalMath, per Mark's recommendation.